# How to implement chained/proxied databindings

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, devexpress

I have this problem in my mvvm wpf application where I want to create proxied/chained databindings.

My ModelViewController looks like this:

```
public class ListViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Contact> GridData { get; private set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Contact> SelectedEntities { get; private set; }
    public bool IsSingeselect { get { return SelectedEntities.Count == 1; } }
    public bool IsMultiSelect { get { return SelectedEntities.Count > 0; } }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuComandModel> ContextMenuItems { get; private set; }
}
```

`GridData` and `SelectedEntities` is bound to a datagrid and works like a charm. I'm using the `ContextMenuItems` collection to create [BarButtonItems](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/clsDevExpressXpfBarsBarButtonItemtopic) for the datagrids contextmenu, this works very good. The `MenuComandModel` class has a `Enabled` attribute and  I want to bind this on the `IsSingeselect` or `IsMultiSelect` attribute to the `BarButtonItems` member `IsEnabled` . How would I archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using DevExpress you can use all the benefits of [DevExpress MVVM Framework](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument15112) and their [POCO-ViewModels](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument17352):

```
using DevExpress.Mvvm.POCO;
//...
public class ListViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<Contact> GridData { get; private set; }

    // mark the SelectedEntities property as virtual to be notified on initializing/replacing
    public virtual ObservableCollection<Contact> SelectedEntities { get; private set; }
    // unsubscribe the CollectionChanged event in changing-callback
    protected void OnSelectedEntitiesChanging() {
        if(SelectedEntities != null)
            SelectedEntities.CollectionChanged -= SelectedEntities_CollectionChanged;
    }
    // subscribe the CollectionChanged event in changed-callback
    protected void OnSelectedEntitiesChanged() {
        if(SelectedEntities != null)
            SelectedEntities.CollectionChanged += SelectedEntities_CollectionChanged;
        UpdateSelectedEntitiesDependencies();
    }
    void UpdateSelectedEntitiesDependencies() {
        // Raise INPC for dependent properties
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.IsSingeselect);
        this.RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.IsMultiSelect);
        // Raise INPC for dependent properties of child ViewModels
        foreach(var item in ContextMenuItems)
            item.RaisePropertyChanged(x => x.Enabled);
    }
    void SelectedEntities_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) {
        if(e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove || e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
            UpdateSelectedEntitiesDependencies();
    }
    public bool IsSingeselect { get { return SelectedEntities.Count == 1; } }
    public bool IsMultiSelect { get { return SelectedEntities.Count > 0; } }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuComandViewModel> ContextMenuItems { get; private set; }
}

public class MenuComandViewModel {
    public bool Enabled {
        get {
            var parentViewModel = this.GetParentViewModel<ListViewModel>();
            return parentViewModel.IsMultiSelect; // Some implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can **bind** you bar items to the ContextMenuItems collection using the approach described in [MVVM Support in DXBars, DXRibbon and GalleryControl](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument10434) help-article.

Comment: Thanks for your inspiration, this gave me the needed input. I did not switch the viewmodels to poco since I dont have the time. But at last I have a solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that my assistance was helpful!